# generate_tfrecords.py error (pandas -> parsers.py)

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, object-detection, training-data

Im trying to use my own images to train for object identification with tensorflow. I have followed all instructions given by: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10
As im using the command: "python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_imput=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record" in the command prompt i get the following.
[Command prompt error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VslaH.png)

Have anyone recieved the same/similar error and knows how to fix it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your application is looking for a flag named `csv_input` but you're providing a flag named `csv_imput`. Change the flag name and you should be fine.